# mvc4 form wont submit with ie8 but works fine with ff and chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form that i want to post back to a view. I want to do it even if all the elements in the form is filled. In chrome and ff is works. But in ie8 (i think) it wants me to fill all the elements with answers.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("BackToDementia", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
lots of elements

  <input  type="submit" value="Tillbaka" class="btnsubmit" onclick="getTextAreaTxt()" style="float: left">
```

}

Comment: Does `getTextAreaTxt` preventDefault, return false, or otherwise cancel the bubble-up?

Comment: No, or at least i don't think so....

Comment: function getTextAreaTxt() {
    var txt = $("#RiskScoreTextAreaEdit").html();
    sessionStorage.setItem("textAreatext", txt);
}

Comment: feels like it's some kind of auto validation going on. If i press the button it will highlight some radiobuttons.

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console? It could be an issue with storing the item in session storage.

Comment: No, no errors in the session storage :/

Comment: For the ViewModel used, are there any validation attributes supplied?

Comment: it's not supposed to be more then javascript validation.

Comment: it works in ie10 but not ie8. If that helps...

Comment: It has to be some sort of automatic validation that only triggers in IE8 :S because when i press the submit button it highlights radiobuttons.